# How to reduce duplication of html on a pure client-side site

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have an old pure HTML/CSS site that I want to clean up. I have two HTML pages that contain the same navigation bar. If I were using a framework like Django, I would extract that navigation bar HTML code into its own template (navigation.html) and then import that template using `{% include 'navigation.html' %}`. Is there a way to do the same thing without using a heavy framework? At the very least, I don't want to use any server-side scripts.

Comment: I think you are referring to a JavaScript templating engine, such as nunjucks, handlebars...

Comment: Could do it with vanilla JavaScript or jQuery or PHP.

Comment: Can you provide more details for what you mean by a heavy framework? React/Angular don't require any server-side scripts. Handlebars is even smaller, but probably not future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a simple html file you can use HTML `include` like so:

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/navigation.html">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some-menu').load('some-local-path/menu.html');
});
```